# Set a shell array from an array in Perl script

Tags: bash, perl, shell

I have the following Perl script:

```
 sub {
    my $sequence="SEQUENCE1";
    my $sequence2="SEQUENCE2";
    my @Array = ($sequence, $sequence2);
    return \@Array;
 }
 -1
```

I want to retrieve the values of the array via a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
seq=$(perl vectTEST.pl)
# retrieve the column 1 of the Array     
echo $seq[0]
```

My approach doesn't work.

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* actually means nothing to us; if you can detail, maybe we can help better :)

Comment: @ikegami I didn't downvote or close vote anyawy

Comment: In this case, it means "I don't know how to do it". There's nothing about this answer that warrants closing it. [oops, re-posting accidentally deleted comment]

Answer (score 4):

You can't return an array. The concept makes no sense since `print` produces a stream of bytes, not variables.

---

One solution is to output a text representation of the array and have the shell parse it.

For example,

```
$ IFS=$'\n' array=( $(
   perl -e'
      my @array = ("a b", "c d", "e f");
      print "$_\n" for @array;
   '
) )

$ echo ${#array[@]}
3

$ echo "${array[1]}"
c d
```

This particular implementation assumes your array can't contain newlines.

---

The other alternative is to print out shell code that recreates the array and `eval` that code in the shell.

For example,

```
$ eval "array=( $(
   perl -e'
      use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
      my @array = ("a b", "c d", "e f");
      print join " ", map shell_quote($_), @array;
   '
) )"

$ echo ${#array[@]}
3

$ echo "${array[1]}"
c d
```

This is a robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but you need to change vectTEST.pl -- currently you have an anonymous sub that you're not assigning to anything. Change the perl script to:

```
$vect = sub {
    my $sequence="SEQUENCE1";
    my $sequence2="SEQUENCE2";
    my @Array=();
    push(@Array,$sequence,$sequence2);
    return \@Array;
};
1;
```

Then, you can do this in bash:

```
mapfile -t seq < <(perl -E 'do "vectTEST.pl"; say join "\n", @{$vect->()}')
for idx in "${!seq[@]}"; do echo "$idx  ${seq[idx]}"; done
```

```
0  SEQUENCE1
1  SEQUENCE2
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you test your Perl script? In order to have that Perl script give you something to put into your shell script, you to make sure your Perl script works:

```
$ test.pl
```

No output at all.

First issue, you put the whole Perl script in `sub`. Subroutines in Perl don't execute unless you call them. You can't even do that since your subroutine doesn't even have a name. Let's get rid of the subroutine:

```
my $sequence="SEQUENCE1";
my $sequence2="SEQUENCE2";
my @Array = ($sequence, $sequence2);
print  \@Array . "\n";
```

Okay, now let's try the program:

```
$ test.pl   
ARRAY(0x7f8bab8303e0)
```

You're printing out an array reference with that `\` in the front of `@Array`. Let's print out the array itself:

```
my $sequence="SEQUENCE1";
my $sequence2="SEQUENCE2";
my @Array = ($sequence, $sequence2);
print  @Array, "\n";
```

That will now print `@Array`:

```
$ test.pl
SEQUENCE1SEQUENCE2
```

Not quite. There's no spaces between each element. Let's set `$,` which is the *output field separator* to be a single space:

```
my $sequence="SEQUENCE1";
my $sequence2="SEQUENCE2";
my @Array = ($sequence, $sequence2);
$,=' ';
print @Array, "\n";
```

Now:

```
$ test.pl
SEQUENCE1 SEQUENCE2
```

Now, we have a working Perl program that outputs what we need to put into your shell array:

```
seq=($(test.pl))
echo ${seq[*]}
SEQUENCE1 SEQUENCE2
```

When you have an issue, you need to break it down into pieces. Your first issue is that your Perl script wasn't working. Once that was fixed, you could now use it to initialize your array in your Bash shell.

Comment: Note: That will fail if the sequences have spaces.

Comment: What's with using `$,`? `print join ' ', @Array, "\n";` would be better, although you could simply use `print "@Array\n";` here

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll test your suggestions monday :)