# Accessing Perl array in bash

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I have a perl code where I execute some bash commands using backticks. I want to read a perl array in that bash command. My array has some strings and I want to read them in a for loop of bash.

```
my @aArray = (1,2,3,4);
my $command = 'for i in $@aArray; do xxxxx $i; done;';
`$command`
```

I also want to catch error if any part of the loop fails. Thanks

Comment: $@aArray is a typo.. i wanted to type just @aArray.

Comment: See [\[ this \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28241319/1620779)

Comment: I'd suggest just looping in Perl: `for my $i (@array) { `xxxxx $i`; }`.

Comment: I don't think this is quite a duplicate of those questions (or answers).

Comment: @lmran it's better to edit your question to fix `$@aArray` to `@aArray` rather than having it as a comment.  Also, one likely reason the question has gotten a few downvotes is that you haven't given error output.  It's worth adding that in an edit, too, and providing any further details you can.  If you get it working, you can (even should) post it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @chepner has suggested, the code you want looks a bit like this:

```
my @array = (1, 2, 3, 4);
for my $val (@array) {
    # Pick your favourite/the most appropriate mechanism for making system calls
    system("command", $val);
}
```

If you need to make a single call on a remote system, what you could do is something like this:

```
my @array = (1, 2, 3, 4);
my $command = "for i in ("

for my $val(@array) {
    $val =~ s/(?<!\\) /\\ /g; # Escape spaces that haven't already been (if the array elements might contain them)
    $command = "$command $val";
}

$command = $command."); do <command> $i; done;";

system($command);
```

Comment: thats exactly how i have it right now. Its just that i execute this system command on a remote host so it takes a lot of time to open connection for each loop. This is the reason i wanted the whole for loop to execute on the remote host with just one connection.

Comment: I added a version that constructs a full-up `bash` command from your initial array.

Comment: thanks, that will do!

Comment: @lmran IMO, executing on a remote host is significant information that would enhance your question significantly